# Let $f$ be analytic in a vertical strip and $|f(z)| \leq \frac{C}{|z|^{\alpha}}$. Is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x+iy) dy$ constant in the strip?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an analytic function in $S = \{z\in\mathbb{C} : a<\text{Re}(z) < b\}$ for
some $a<b$. Suppose that 
$$|f(z)| \leq \frac{C}{|z|^{\alpha}}$$
for all $z\in S$, some positive constant $C$, and a constant $\alpha>1$. Prove that the function $g$ defined by 
$$g(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x+iy) dy$$
is constant in $(a,b)$.

Usually in problems similar to this one the functions are entire so I can apply Liouiville's theorem but I'm not sure how to proceed with this one. Here one could find $g'$ to show that it's $0$ but I don't know how to go about that either.

Edit: Trying to build on the comment by [reuns](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/276986/reuns) below.

We have $\int_{\gamma} f(z) dz = 0$ for any $\gamma$ inside $S$. Consider the rectangle $R$ with vertices $a_1+iT$, $b_1+iT$, $b_1-iT$, and $a_1-iT$ where $a<a_1<b_1<b$. Since $|f(z)| \leq \frac{C}{|z|^{\alpha}}$, we see that $$\lim_{T\to\infty} \int_{b_1+iT}^{a_1+iT} f(z)\; dz 
=\lim_{T\to\infty} \int_{a_1-iT}^{b_1-iT} f(z)\; dz =0.$$
Therefore, 
$$\lim_{T\to\infty} \int_{a_1-iT}^{a_1+iT} f(z)\; dz 
=
\lim_{T\to\infty} \int_{b_1-iT}^{b_1+iT} f(z)\; dz,$$
i.e., $g(a_1)=g(b_1)$.

Comment: Sure, $g(x_1)=g(x_2)$ is the Cauchy integral theorem applied to the boundary of $\Re(z)\in (x_1,x_2)$.

Comment: Another approach, $$\frac{d}{dx}g(x)=\int^\infty_{-\infty}f’(x+iy)dy=-i[f(x+iy)]^{\infty}_{-\infty}=0$$ But you need to justify a lot of things.